# Are property path depths actually usable in jena sparql?

Tags: sparql, jena

I've got the following query in Jena.

```
PREFIX edge: <http://test.com/edge#>
PREFIX property: <http://test.com/property#>
select  distinct ?supertype ?subtype where{
?supertype edge:uses{1,3} ?subtype.
?subtype (edge:extends | edge:implements)+ ?supertype. }
```

which works fine in sesame, but in jena i get the following error:

Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 1, column 163.
Was expecting one of:

Also I've tried setting it to use sparql 1, 1.1 and the ARQ syntax, but always the same error. Though the same query works in sesame2. So my question is, is the syntax slightly different in Jenas sparql or is it unsupported? (I'm assuming from http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/property_paths.html that it is supported.)

Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jena is now an Apache project - the website is http://jena.apache.org/.  The SF documentation is legacy and there to maintain old links.

{} syntax is not part of SPARQL 1.1 (it got removed)

You can use Syntax.syntaxARQ to get extended syntax which does include {}/

You can use http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html to check.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason the query does work in Sesame is that it still supports the `{x, y}` syntax for property paths, even though it has been removed from the official standard. It hasn't been decided yet if it will be left in in the future though.